# Meteor: why certain js files are not automatically loaded?

Tags: meteor

For example (even trying to use the library from console after X seconds or with a setTimeout):

client/kiwi.mini.js (from https://github.com/gamelab/kiwi.js)

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
>   debug.js:41 ReferenceError: Kiwi is not defined

When kiwi is loaded standalone with

```
<script src
```

within a normal HTML page, it just works (new Kiwi...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last little bit of the huge unminified JS file is minified, so it's hard to tell for sure, but it doesn't look like `Kiwi` is being added to the `window` object in their code. Since Meteor compiles all JS files and makes any variable that has a `var` in front of it local to that JS file, the Kiwi object is not available globally.

Simply add one line of code to the end of the minified file:

```
window.Kiwi = Kiwi;
```

I've tested it in a sample Meteor app and was able to create a `new Kiwi.Game` object.